# Pandas Dataframe Forward Fill upto current quarter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am looking for a forward fill of a dataframe upto the present quarter of year.

I have following dataframe:

```
Quarter Name Value
2016Q4  A     2
2017Q1  B     3
2017Q2  C     1
```

Output required:

```
Quarter Name Value
2016Q4  A     2
2017Q1  B     3
2017Q2  C     1
2017Q3  C     1
```

Please note that the 2017Q3 is the current quarter and that is what is required to be forward filled.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that `Quarter` is a period column

```
df.Quarter = pd.PeriodIndex(df.Quarter, freq='Q')
```

Use `pd.period_range` to build a new index then `reindex`

```
idx = pd.period_range(df.Quarter.min(), pd.datetime.now(), freq='Q')
df.set_index('Quarter').reindex(idx, method='ffill').reset_index()

   index Name  Value
0 2016Q4    A      2
1 2017Q1    B      3
2 2017Q2    C      1
3 2017Q3    C      1
```

---

To be super safe and only add new index values from the current most recent quarter to the present

```
pidx = pd.PeriodIndex(df.Quarter, freq='Q')
nidx = pd.period_range(pidx.max(), pd.datetime.now(), freq='Q')

df.Quarter = pidx

df.set_index('Quarter').reindex(pidx.union(nidx), method='ffill').reset_index()

   index Name  Value
0 2016Q4    A      2
1 2017Q1    B      3
2 2017Q2    C      1
3 2017Q3    C      1
```